# pfbc change required using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using PFBC to build my forms and jquery for validation. I have one element:

```
array (
     'name' => 'bank[Bank Name]',
     'label' => $this->t('Bank Name'),
     'type' => 'Textbox',
     'properties' => array (
          'id' => 'bank_name',
           'required' => 1,
      )

),
```

Based on a select value of another field, I want to hide it and make it not-required, or the opposite.

```
if ($('select[name=type]').val() == 'bank_wire_transfer') {
     $('#element_bank_name').slideDown();
     $('#element_bank_name').attr("required")=1;
}
else{
      $('#element_bank_name').slideUp();
     $('#element_bank_name').attr("required")=0;
}
```

But this code, and many other variations I tried, do not work. The field remains required and I cannot submit my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example, PFBC will create:
1. an element that contains both the label and the input type with id='#element_bank_name'
2. the input type will have id='bank_name'

So, to hide the entire element you do:

```
$('#element_bank_name').slideUp();
```

And to change the input element value you do:

```
$('#bank_name').val("");
```